# Finding a Summation in range

Tags: algorithm, tree

I have given an Array A and B. Where B contains the indexes of A.
Let
A = [2,3,5,6,7,8,9]
B = [1,3,1,4,5,2,6]

I have given `Q` queries where i have to find the Sum in the Range `L to R` using B.

```
Example L=2 , R=4

Sum =  A[B[2]]+A[B[3]]+ A[B[4]]
Sum =  A[3] + A[1]+A[4] = 5+2+6=13 

Now a Query for update i.e 
U 2 10
A[2] =10 // previously 3
S 6 7
Sum = A[B[6]]+A[B[7]] = A[2]+A[6]=10+8=18
```

Is there any solution better than `O(Q*N)` , any data structure which support both **update and summation** in this case. (Segment Tree and BITS like)

Constraints:

```
N,Q,Value<10^6
```

Comment: Any constraint? number of query? number of elements? number of element each index of A can be referred by B?

Comment: @PhamTrung updated the question